# What reasons (if any) exist for prohibiting script import?

Tags: python, python-import

An executable script usually looks like this:

```
import modules
define some CONSTANTS, Classes, functions
if __name__ == "__main__":
    really_do_something()
```

Recently I saw a script using the negated form of the commonn idiom:

```
if __name__ != "__main__":
    print('The executable must not be imported.')
    sys.exit(1)
```

I find it not Pythonic. Why should anybody want to prevent *consenting adults* to import the file? Are there valid reasons?

I could not find any reasons, except that it is simpler to write this `!=` guard on the top of the script compared to the standard `==` guard near the bottom of the script.

Even if the answer looks obvious, given the complexity of Python import system I decided to ask just to be sure.

Comment: The script specifically expects to be executed in a command line environment and the author found it easier to explicitly handle it this way than to anticipate some other use case…?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the possibility that the script executes immediate actions. That is, there are commands at "module scope" in the script file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
with open('/etc/passwd') as pwd:
    ...
```

In this case, importing the file will cause those commands to be run. And while it may provide some subroutines or class definitions, it might not.

So putting in a warning saying "you imported this, but you shouldn't, because it won't do what you want" is a friendly thing. It really says "this file isn't set up to be imported. If you want this functionality, call `system`"

Comment: I think this is the same situation as I outlined in the question: all actions should be taking place below the `if __name__ == "__main__"` line, but it is simpler not to support importing. Anyway I'm glad no other reason came to light.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If the script is just a quick-and-dirty script to do some simply stuff, then I don't see any point in importing it. Just copy&paste what you need into your code and you are done (obviously I'm assuming a compatible open source license).

If the script is part of some library/software, then the best practice would be that each script should be of the form:

```
import argparse
from somewhere import main

args = <parse-arguments>

main(args)
```

In other words: it does not contain *anything*, it just imports stuff, parses the command line arguments and calls the `main` function. In this case it does not make sense to import this script, because it's empty. You can just perform the imports yourself, removing the argument parsing stuff.

This is where such a guard might be useful. Since it does not make any logical senso to import the script, maybe you can tell the user that instead of importing the script they should simply import the `main` function.

If, however, the script is complex, imports stuff, defines classes, functions, glues pieces together etc, then yes it does make sense to import it and in this case using a guard similar to the one you provided as an example limits the usefulness of the script.

However note that the script might contain some logic executed when defining the module, in this case importing it might be useless (however the script should be refactored to place such logic in a functin that can be safely imported instead).

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not understand this part _"Since it does not make any logical senso to import the script, maybe you can tell the user that instead of importing the script they should simply import the main function."_ I think it is not possible.

Comment: @VPfB What is not possible? Prevent script import? That's what your example code *does*, so it *is* possible. In the exception message you can write what you want, including a suggestion to just import the main function

Comment: I think it is not possible to prevent script import and to allow import main from the script in the same time.

Comment: @VPfB It is easily done. script `A.py` does `if __name__ != '__main__': raise ImportError`. Then users just do `from somewhereelse import main`.  The point is that the user should **not** import `main` thourgh `A.py`, they should import it from the same module that `A.py` imports it from.

Comment: @VPfB That's why it does not make sense ot import `A.py`. It just import `main` from a different module and calls it. If you want to use `main` there is no point in messing with `A.py`, go directly for the module that defines it.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean - to import _from elsewhere_ is the key point I have overlooked. This is indeed a possible explanation why the author wrote it that way. But he did not have to, he could use the standard idiom as well. So the main question is still: Are there any reasons to prohibit import or else something bad would happen?